# Отправка файла на сервер с заменой с помощью встроенной утилиты ftp.exe посредством запуска cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, ftp, ftp-сервер

Необходимо создать код файла cmd, который будет лежать рядом с целевым файлом. При запуске этого cmd, целевой файл отправляется на ftp-сервер и заменяет там файл с таким же названием и расширением.

Answer (score 0):

Если стандартным ftp клиентом, то синтаксис такой:

```
ftp -n -s:script.txt ftp-server.net
```

**script.txt** - скрипт со списком следующих команд:

```
user guest
password
quote pasv
bin
cd public
put file.bin
quit
```

1. задает имя пользователя [guest].
2. вводит пароль [password].
3. задает пассивный режим работы.
4. включает бинарный режим обмена.
5. меняет текущий каталог на удаленном сервере [public].
6. загружает файл на удаленный сервер [file.bin].
7. завершает сеанс.

Comment: Кончено, можно все это запихать в один batch-файл. Но это уже детали. Также следует учитывать, что локальным каталогом (в среде ftp-сеанса) считается текущий путь, откуда была вызвана команда ftp.exe